Setting the intercept to zero in this linear regression results in unbiased and less variable estimates - but is it theoretically justified?
Based on feedback I got from our statisticians, and having seen this post, I was pretty sure that one almost never sets the intercept to zero in a linear regression.
However, I recently came across some results in our corporate database, which implied that linear regressions were run with a fixed intercept.
I set up some simulations (R code below), essentially thinking I would just confirm that the correct approach was to leave the intercept free to vary.
And to my complete amazement, I found that instead, especially for $N = 2$, fixing the intercept to its theoretical value resulted in unbiased and less variable estimates(!).
I would really like to understand what is going on, if I am mistaken somewhere in my approach, or if this is indeed a case where it is legitimate to fix the intercept.
To keep it very simple:

HPLC area ($A$) vs time ($t$) data are collected, which are expected to fit this function: $A(t) = A_0 \cdot e^{-k \cdot t}$
this is normally fitted as $\ln[A(t)] = \ln[A_0] -k \cdot t$
the parameter of interest is $k$
$A_0$ is the 'true' initial area, which is not known; it is estimated by measuring $A(t)$ at a time very close to $0$
$A(t)$ is log-normally distributed, with ~constant standard deviation $SD_{ln A(t)} \approx 0.023$
the company who generates these data does not provide $A(t)$: they divide all $A(t)$'s by the measured $A(0)$ and provide the $R(t) = A(t)/A(0)$ ratios
as I discovered the other day, they actually fit $\ln[R(t)] = -k \cdot t$, i.e. they fix the intercept to $0$

I thought this approach (fixing the intercept) was wrong, for two reasons.
First, $A(0)$ is measured, so it's subject to uncertainty just like any other $A(t)$, whereas the equation they are using for fitting seems to assume that they know an exact value of $A_0$.
Second, you can imagine a case where this measured $A(0)$ is very low, so all your $R(t)$'s become $>>1$. Then fixing the intercept to $0$ would bias the $k$, by forcing the line to pass through the origin, when in such a case it most definitely shouldn't. Similar reasoning for $A(0)$ being very high.
So for me it really only made sense to make no assumptions about the ratio between each $A(t)$ and the 'true' $A(0)$, and just fit:
$\ln[R(t)] = intercept -k \cdot t$
i.e. leaving the intercept estimate the 'true' value of $\ln [R_0]$.
Yes, $\ln [R_0]$ is expected to be $0$. Is this sufficient to justify setting it to $0$?
It turns out I was probably wrong.
From the R simulation below, you can see that the method where the intercept is fixed, especially when only 2 time points are collected (in addition to time $0$), results in no bias on $k$ (or at least, the median is well aligned, it seems), and in fact the variability on $k$ is reduced(!).
What do you think? Is this a case where it makes sense to fix the intercept? Would you suggest any alternative approach?
R script (ignore the 'concentration' references - it is essentially the same as areas)
# Number of simulations per true k
N = 1000

# Time points (min) to collect, in addition to time 0
times = c(25, 40)

# True k's
ks = c(0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0005)
ks = c(ks, ks * 10, ks * 100)

# Exact initial concentration (uM)
C0 = 1

# Exact time courses
timecourses = list()
for (k in ks) {
  timecourse = sapply(times, function(ti) C0 * exp(-k * ti))
  timecourses = c(timecourses, list(c(C0, timecourse)))
}

# Simulation of measured concentrations (with random error)
set.seed(49856)
ks_measured = list()
k0s_measured = list()

for (tc in timecourses) {
  ln_tc = log(tc)
  ks_m = numeric()
  k0s_m = numeric()
  for (i in 1:N) {
    ln_tc_m = ln_tc + rnorm(n = length(ln_tc), mean = 0, sd = 0.023)
    ln_fr_m = ln_tc_m[2:length(ln_tc_m)] - ln_tc_m[1]
    # print(ln_fr_m)
    k = -coef(lm(y ~ x, 
           data = list("x" = times, "y" = ln_fr_m )))[["x"]]
    k0 = -coef(lm(y ~ x + 0, 
           data = list("x" = times, "y" = ln_fr_m )))[["x"]]
    # print(k)
    ks_m = c(ks_m, k)
    k0s_m = c(k0s_m, k0)
  }
  ks_measured = c(ks_measured, list(ks_m))
  k0s_measured = c(k0s_measured, list(k0s_m))
}

df = data.frame("k_true" = rep(ks, each = N), 
    "k_measured" = unlist(ks_measured), 
    "method" = "free intercept" )
df0 = data.frame("k_true" = rep(ks, each = N), 
     "k_measured" = unlist(k0s_measured), 
     "method" = "fixed intercept" )
df = rbind(df, df0)

boxplot(k_measured ~ method + k_true, data = df, 
    col = rep(c(2,3), length(ks)))
# abline(h = ks, col = 2, lty = 2)

Plot it produces:

Further info:
aggregate(df, by = df[,c("method","k_true")], FUN = sd)
            method k_true k_true   k_measured method
1  fixed intercept  1e-04      0 0.0008375890     NA
2   free intercept  1e-04      0 0.0021145500     NA
3  fixed intercept  2e-04      0 0.0008266349     NA
4   free intercept  2e-04      0 0.0021941700     NA
5  fixed intercept  5e-04      0 0.0008874865     NA
6   free intercept  5e-04      0 0.0020413706     NA
7  fixed intercept  1e-03      0 0.0008409697     NA
8   free intercept  1e-03      0 0.0021750154     NA
9  fixed intercept  2e-03      0 0.0008463917     NA
10  free intercept  2e-03      0 0.0022112687     NA
11 fixed intercept  5e-03      0 0.0008408110     NA
12  free intercept  5e-03      0 0.0021396045     NA
13 fixed intercept  1e-02      0 0.0008389027     NA
14  free intercept  1e-02      0 0.0021770484     NA
15 fixed intercept  2e-02      0 0.0008385624     NA
16  free intercept  2e-02      0 0.0022633057     NA
17 fixed intercept  5e-02      0 0.0008467246     NA
18  free intercept  5e-02      0 0.0021269290     NA

